# Sphinx - GROUP BY ROLLUP

Tags: sphinx

Is there a way to do a search with GROUP BY ROLLUP like MySQL.
I am trying to get a summary of Year/Month/Day so I can build a single facet tree and show users the spread of results.

If it is not possible I am thinking that the only way would be to do a facet by DATE and summarise the tree in PHP.

ps. Currently I do facets but they are only at one level at a time, summarise all the years, when user selects a year I then filter that year and summarise all the months etc but I want to get a single summary in one go.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no 'WITH ROLLUP'.

Its common run a normal query alongside the group-by query (in fact FACET is a shorthand to do a normal query, along with a number of group by) - so you can get the sum count from the total_count of that query.